# Java: Converting number to binary and sorting from input class

Tags: java, sorting

I am having trouble converting these number to binary from input file. Then I am suppose to sort the binary number  with the smallest
number of ones will be first and the numbers with the largest number of ones will be last. If two
numbers have the same number of ones, sort the numbers first by the base 10 value. 
If the base 10 values are the same, then sort the numbers by their original values. Print out the original number, its
value in base 10, and finally, print out the numbers value in binary. Enter the file name from the
keyboard. I have to use the Comparable interface.

If some can just help me converting input file to binary that would be helpful enough.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //Prompt the user and asks for filename. 
    System.out.print("Enter the file name: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    
    String file = in.next();    //input file name


    //Takes input and reads from file. 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){

    // Input file read. 
    System.out.println(input.nextLine());

    }
```

Comment: what is your input variable type? are they just a list of integers?

Comment: Yes it is a list of integers from a text file

Comment: What is the difference between "original number" and "its value in base 10"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
List<BigInteger> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
new Scanner(new FileReader(new File(""))).forEachRemaining(s -> numbers.add(new BigInteger(s)));
numbers.sort(Comparator.<BigInteger>comparingLong(i -> i.toString(2).chars().filter(b -> b == '1').count())
                       .thenComparing(Function.identity()));
numbers.forEach(i -> System.out.format("%d - %s%n", i, i.toString(2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You first should save each line as an integer. Since it's a list that needs to be sorted, consider using an array.

```
int[] array = new array[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    array[i] = input.nextLine();
}
```

Then you can use the built in method Integer.toBinaryString. It will return the variable type string of the integer.

```
String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(array[i])
```